# How to get deleted list item from custom listView android?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I am using custom listview with `TextView` and `ImageButton`. On click event of button i want to delete that item from list and get the `textview's` text and pass it to activity.

Here is my code...

**Adapter**

```
//getView
TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    ImageButton imageButtonClear = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonClear);

    textView.setText(document.getDocName());

    imageButtonClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            documentList.remove(i);
            CustomAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

**Activity**

```
//setting listview adapter
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context,documentList);
    listViewDoc.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    //How to get deleted item from list here...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `interface` in `Adapter` i.e. `OnItemClearListener`

```
public interface OnItemClearListener{
     void onItemClear(String itemName);
}
```

Implement `OnItemClearListener` in `Activity`

and pass `Activity` reference in `Adapter`

```
customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context,documentList,this);
```

Create variable of `OnItemClearListener` and assign its value in `CustomAdapter`.

and call method of interface like this.

```
imageButtonClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onItemClearListener.onItemClear(document.getDocName());
        documentList.remove(i);
        CustomAdapter.this.notifyItemRemoved(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are deleting the row store that list name in one ArrayList/Array and pass it to Activity.

```
TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    ImageButton imageButtonClear = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonClear);

 List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(); // Here creating an array

    textView.setText(document.getDocName());

    imageButtonClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            documentList.remove(i);
            data.add(document.getDocName()); // here adding data to arraylist
            CustomAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: how do i pass it to activity...?

Comment: every deleting , do you want to pass it to activity ? @M.Usman

Comment: yes. I want every item deleted from lsit on instance.

Comment: at same time do you want to go to activity with value or else ? @M.Usman

Answer (score 0):

**Write a public method in your activity**

```
public void setDeletedItem(String documentName)
    {
       //get values from object 
    Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("VALUE",documentName);
    startActivity(intent);
    }



imageButtonClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mContext instanceof YourActivity) {
                    ((YourActivity) mContext).setDeletedItem(documentList.get(i).getDocName());
                }
            documentList.remove(i);
            CustomAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    })
```

;